# Sampling of sine wave :which one to choose? start with zeroth sample or 1st sample

Tags: frequency

sampling rate=200KHz
signal freq =1KHz
When I sample 1KHz signal I'll get 200 samples.

Should I consider 0 to 199 samples?
Or 1 to 200?
I want only 1 cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both give you a cycle, just at a different starting point; but the thing about periodicity is that its periodic, regardless of the starting point.

So, there's no wrong answer here.

Comment: Thank you! I want to get one complete cycle. Starting from zero to zero. Is this possible ?

Comment: I answered that in my answer, literally.

Comment: Start with 0 and end with 0.If I do this number of samples will be 201.Is this correct ?

Comment: a complete cycle is 200, not 201 samples.

Comment: so, it is not possible to get complete cycle starting from zero and ending at zero. Either the signal starts from 0 and ends at less than zero(sample value is less than zero at 199th position)        or    starts from 1st sample(sample value greater than 0) and perfectly ends at 0. Is my understanding correct? please tell if not

Comment: That understanding is correct. If you take a piece of paper and draw a sine on it with equidistant sampling points, you'll see as much.

Comment: Thank you!The requirement is to get one complete cycle from 0 to 0..I have come to know that it is not possible..right?

Comment: I'm not keen on repeating things that I've already said.

Comment: @KA Look at the _tail end_ of [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/4843/235) for an explanation of why you _don't_ want to satisfy your  manager's heart's desire of "one complete cycle from $0$ to $0$".

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate,Oh Thank you! Found the answer for my question why it is not possible to get "one complete cycle from 0 to  0"..Answer is crystal clear!!

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate, the explanation is very good. But when it comes  to repeating the set of samples and generating signals with particular  frequency with 20 cycles in the signal I never get a signal which completes full cycle

Comment: Your definition of "full cycle" is wrong if it's not 20 samples for a signal with a period of 20 samples.